# RTSP breaks SSL

Tags: ssl, jwplayer

Is there a way to prevent jwplayer from disabling the green SSL when streaming realtime?

Also if I am on an SSL website, are all the relative-to-the-site AJAX script calls automatically secured?

Comment: RTSP is a format that isn't even supported by the JW Player? Confused.

Comment: Oh, got it. Do you have an example of where this is happening?